# Angular 2+ sliding sidebar outside router outlet

Tags: angular, sidebar, router-outlet, sidenav

I am trying to implement a sidebar that opens up on various button clicks throughout the application ("more info" type of functionality). For that reason I am looking to place the sidebar component outside the router outlet.

app-component:

```
<nav>
<router-outlet>
<sidebar>
```

When the sidebar is open, I would like to grey out the rest of the screen and have a click anywhere (besides the sidebar close the sidebar). The way I thought to do it is wrap the nav and router-outlet in a div with a click event to close the sidebar. Sidebar open/close/toggle is managed with a service. The issue I'm having is wrapping the router-outlet (and nav) like that overrides the actual button clicks inside the routes meant to open the sidebar. Any advice? Many thanks

Comment: Please provide example code that you currently have and if possible create a demo using https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular I’ll then be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to have the sidebar react based upon subscribing to an observable, or behaviorsubject. I used a BehaviorSubject to receive commands, and subscribed to it in another part of the program, and having it react accordingly. Kinda like a messaging system for your app. It worked really well for me! You w oi uld drive it based on onclicks and forget routing altogether for that part of it.

I dont think you would do this within the sidebar, but rather the controller that hosts the sidebar e.g. the parent. If you need code let me know, but I thought this answer would send you down the right path.

The other thing you can do is once you have control of the slider, you could have it pop a modal div. I dont have any code for that though.

Comment: I use this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp. You just need to convert the javascript to angular and is fairly easy. Just use Event Emitter to control the header to the the main. Let me know if you have any questions.